# How to create a Java annotation containing an array of unknown enums?

Tags: java, enums, annotations

The annotation I am trying to make looks something like this

```
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = { ElementType.FIELD })
public @interface EnumParameter {
    Enum<?>[] disallowedValues() default {};
}
```

However, I get the following error "Invalid type Enum[] for the annotation attribute EnumParameter.disallowedValues; only primitive type, String, Class, annotation, enumeration are permitted or 1-dimensional arrays thereof" about it. I intend to use this to indicate that some values within an enum are not valid for this field. I don't know the type because I intend to use this to supplement UI creation and thus any type of enum could be encountered.

---

edit for clarification.

Say I have an enum,

```
enum Direction{
    LEFT, RIGHT, BOTH;
}
```

and I have a field,

```
Direction turnSignal;
```

I would like to indicate that the turn signal cannot have the BOTH.

```
@EnumParameter(disallowedValues = {Direction.BOTH})
Direction turnSignal;
```

---

I've been made aware of the fact that this seems to be an impossibility as of now. Is there a reason that this was disallowed? Is it considered bad style to use enum's in this fashion?

Comment: Not possible. Enum values must be known in the compile time.

Comment: What do you mean by _values within an enum_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Say for example, we have an enum Direction, which enumerates LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN; and we want to then annotate a field called turnSignal. Well, turnsignal is a direction, but it cannot indicate up or down, so I would like to indicate that within the tag.

Comment: I think you would be better served by performing that logic in your class methods that set the `turnSignal`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The annotations are to enable procedural generation of UI components, and I would prefer to not write special handling for all cases like this.

Comment: Its not going to work. The best you'll get if you want to use enums is to make disallowedValues an integer which will have to correspond to the ordinal of the relevant enum. You'd have to make sure you've then got unit tests to check if the ordinal changes due to adding another enum value. It's messy but I can't think of anything better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work:

```
@Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass(); 
    String[] disallowedValues();
}
```

Used like

```
@MyAnnotation(enumClass = Direction.class, disallowedValues = {"LEFT", "RIGHT"})
Direction turnSignal;
```

Comment: It would get me there, and it may be the only way to get there. Its unfortunate that it needs to be unnecessarily verbose, will not survive a refactoring, and leaves itself open to user errors with typos.